# Watch for object properties changes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, cross-browser, properties, watch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Object.Watch for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers)

I just read Mozilla's documentation for the [watch() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch). It looks very useful.

However, I can't find something similar for Safari. Neither Internet Explorer.

How do you manage portability across browsers?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers

Comment: Here's a related discussion:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I have created a small [object.watch shim](https://gist.github.com/384583) for this a while ago. It works in IE8, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.

```
/*
* object.watch v0.0.1: Cross-browser object.watch
*
* By Elijah Grey, http://eligrey.com
*
* A shim that partially implements object.watch and object.unwatch
* in browsers that have accessor support.
*
* Public Domain.
* NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.
*/

// object.watch
if (!Object.prototype.watch)
    Object.prototype.watch = function (prop, handler) {
        var oldval = this[prop], newval = oldval,
        getter = function () {
            return newval;
        },
        setter = function (val) {
            oldval = newval;
            return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
        };
        if (delete this[prop]) { // can't watch constants
            if (Object.defineProperty) // ECMAScript 5
                Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                    get: getter,
                    set: setter
                });
            else if (Object.prototype.__defineGetter__ && Object.prototype.__defineSetter__) { // legacy
                Object.prototype.__defineGetter__.call(this, prop, getter);
                Object.prototype.__defineSetter__.call(this, prop, setter);
            }
        }
    };

// object.unwatch
if (!Object.prototype.unwatch)
    Object.prototype.unwatch = function (prop) {
        var val = this[prop];
        delete this[prop]; // remove accessors
        this[prop] = val;
    };
```

Comment: Any reason as to why you removed it from Github? Better solution? Wasn't working? How about IE7?

Comment: It's still on Github, I just move it to a gist (https://gist.github.com/384583) due to it not really being significant enough for a repo imo.

Comment: how do we use this to monitor innerHTML on DOM objects?

Comment: Does it actually work for IE8 on non DOM objects?

Comment: This does not work in Safari on certain DOM properties such as `el.style.width`

Comment: After using watch, i can't iterate through attributes. Maybe better to remove line with "delete this[prop]" ?

Comment: IE8 shows error on line "Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {" - the command is not supported by the object.

Comment: @Eli Grey. I think that if your solution works in IE8 only for DOM object you MUST note it.

Comment: I think this code should work great for POCO object. For DOM element, you should consider attrchange library(https://github.com/meetselva/attrchange).

Comment: For any other object types(rather than POCO object), I think we should not use this function to detect change because it may causes a problem because most of they are native code. It should not be a good idea to modify them.

Comment: can't watch constants, -1

Comment: when you console.log() that object, the watched property is hidden!!!! how to fix??

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not a portable solution.  IE has nothing like this to my knowledge, though it would be awesome if there was

Answer (score -4):

You could probably implement your own system of notifcation, by overwriting methods and variables. I don't see it as being that critical though, but I don't know what you planning on doing with such a system.