# Accessing properties hidden by __defineGetter__/__defineSetter__ in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs, innerhtml, getter-setter

I am trying to define a custom setter for the `innerHTML` property. Unfortunately, i am unable to access the underlying property after i define the setter function:

```
$('body')[0].__defineSetter__("innerHTML",
  function (val) {
    alert("Setting to: " + val);
    this.innerHTML = val;
});
```

This snippet fills the call stack because the assignment calls the setter recursively.
Apparenly `innerHTML` is already an overloaded property in IE8 and you can simply save the older get/set pair and use it inside the new property descriptor. Taken from MSDN:

```
var innerHTMLdescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, 'innerHTML');
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'innerHTML',
  { set: function(htmlVal) {
      var safeHTML = toStaticHTML(htmlVal);
      innerHTMLdescriptor.set.call(this, safeHTML);
    }
});
```

However, this seems to be not the case for Chrome, where `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` returns undefined for `innerHTML`. In this case, how do I access the underlying property?

Bonus question: how do I ensure that all objects created in the future have this special `innerHTML` behaviour? Is it possible to use DOM prototypes for this? It seems that overloading a function is not what i need here. Perhaps it is possible to overload the DOM constructor and add a call `__defineGetter__/defineProperty` but it looks like support for constructors is not common so I'd like to know if there is any alternative.

Comment: Don't use \_\_defineSetter\_\_ in actual production code - it's non-standard and may exclude the users of many browsers.

Comment: the standard-equivalent is `defineProperty` right? still, the problem of referencing the hidden the property exists...

Comment: No, it's still not really a standard. You shouldn't use it because it excludes older browsers. Of course, if you're doing something non-crucial and it degrades gracefully, it's OK. But it doesn't look like it will in your case.

Comment: formally it seems to be a standard (ecmascript 5), but yes, i agree that it doesn't have great compatibility yet. don't worry, i'm not developing any of your favorite web applications :D

Comment: Outlook not so good. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920180/definesetter-on-innerhtml-stops-it-from-rendering

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a separate datastore property to store the actual value, much like with other languages that use getters and setters. You can use closures to make them hidden.

```
var _innerHTML = "";

this.__defineSetter__( "innerHTML",
    function (val) {
        alert("Setting to: " + val);
        _innerHTML = val;
    } );

this.__defineGetter__( "innerHTML",
    function () {
        return _innerHTML;
    } );
```

However, I've found that using getters and setters on existing DOM properties often simply won't work, due to the special handling of these properties internally. For example, it won't work with the `value` property of a text `input`. I'd expect `innerHTML` to be in the same boat.