# Listen for change to Javascript object value

Tags: javascript

Is it possible (using jQuery or otherwise) to listen for a change in the value of a non-DOM Javascript object (or variable)?

So, for instance, I have:

```
function MyObject(){
    this.myVar = 0;
}

var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.myVar = 100;
```

Is there a way to listen for when the value of `myVar` changes and call a function?

I know that I could use getter/setters, but they aren't supported in previous versions of IE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Watch for object properties changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269633/javascript-watch-for-object-properties-changes)

Comment: There is a proposed Object.observe() https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/11/Respond-to-change-with-Object-observe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If IE is important, I guess you are not interested in [Watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)

But someone seems to have written a shim which makes this question a duplicate

[Watch for object properties changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269633/javascript-watch-for-object-properties-changes)

Comment: This is probably the best solution available - it still excludes IE7, but in a world with IE, nothing can be perfect... :)

Comment: Downvoting without commenting is not helping anyone

Answer (score 12):

Basically you have two options

- use non-standard `watch` method which is available only in Firefox
- use getters and setters which are not supported in older IE versions

The third and cross-platform option is to use polling which is not so great

**Example of `watch`**

```
var myObject = new MyObject();

// Works only in Firefox
// Define *watch* for the property
myObject.watch("myVar", function(id, oldval, newval){
    alert("New value: "+newval);
});

myObject.myVar = 100; // should call the alert from *watch*
```

**Example of `getters` and `setters`**

```
function MyObject(){
    // use cache variable for the actual value
    this._myVar = undefined;
}

// define setter and getter methods for the property name
Object.defineProperty(MyObject.prototype, "myVar",{
    set: function(val){
        // save the value to the cache variable
        this._myVar = val;
        // run_listener_function_here()
        alert("New value: " + val);
    },
    get: function(){
        // return value from the cache variable
        return this._myVar;
    }
});

var m = new MyObject();
m.myVar = 123; // should call the alert from *setter*
```

Comment: When you say "older versions of IE" does this include IE8? I know it _is_ old, but does it support getter & setters?

Comment: This answer is from 2011. IE8 was not so old back then.

Answer (score 3):

You can basically implement such behavior

```
function MyObject(onMyVarChangedCallback)
{
    this.myVar = 0;

    this.setMyVar = function (val) {
       this.MyVar = val;

       if (onMyVarChangedCallback) {
           onMyVarChangedCallback();
       }
    }
}

function onChangeListener() {
   alert('changed');
}

var o = new MyObject(onChangeListener);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with setting the value like a setter though, right? `o.myVar = 100` wouldn't work, it would have to be `o.setMyVar(100)`  That's what I'm trying to avoid - I'd like to have it function like a setter, though it looks like that might not be possible when keeping support in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

## *Constructor-level*

#### property change listener using getter & setter

Internally listen inside the constructor using a trick to define custom property `myVar` on the `this` reference of the constructor.

```js
function MyObject() {
  this._myVar = 0;

  Object.defineProperties(this, {
      "myVar": {
           get(){
                return this._myVar
           },
           set(v, cb){ 
              this._myVar = v
              console.log("myVar has changed to ", v)
           }
      }
  })
}

var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.myVar = 100;
console.log(myObject.myVar)
```

## *Instance-level*

#### property change listener using a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Proxies are "traps" which wraps anything of type `Object` and can then listen to any `get` or `set` to it.

This method creates a listener for any instance of the constructor you desire, unlike the previous method, it only apply to the instance.

By instantiating inside a proxy `new Proxy(new MyObject(), {...}` and then apply `get` & [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set) (to simply, only [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set) is needed) it is possible to listen to any change of any property of the instance. If you want to listen to only one property and act to it, that add more logic inside the [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set) statement.

```js
function MyObject() {
  this.myVar = 0
  this.name = 'cool'
}

var myObjectProxy = new Proxy(new MyObject(), {
  set(target, property, value) {
    console.log(property, "has changed to ", value)

    target[property] = value;

    // return "true" accepts the change
    return true;
  }
})

myObjectProxy.myVar = 100
console.log(myObjectProxy)
```