# How would I set up a jasmine spy to return a value from an input box based on the passed in selector in jQuery?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to create a spy on Jquery that's making a call like:

```
$('#AccountNumber').val();
```

How would I set up the spy to return a value based on the #AccountNumber selector?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var spy = ('#AccountNumber', 'ValueChanged');
$('#AccountNumber').trigger('ValueChanged');
expect(spy).toHaveBeenTriggered();
var val = $(spy.selector).val();
```

**Update after edit:**
You could add this -
[Watch for object properties changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269633/watch-for-object-properties-changes-in-javascript)
then inside handler trigger event 'ValueChanged', and on spy add listener to that event.