# How to use obj.watch() in jQuery Plugin?

Tags: jquery, object, plugins, watch

I would like to set up some watchers in my jQuery plugin to can fire on certain cases different methods. I see this one is related to browsers.

Is there a good way to watch object changes in plugin?

I was trying to use like

```
var arrival_date = {
                'test': ''
            };
arrival_date.watch('test', function() {
                alert();
            });
```

but I get `Uncaught TypeError: arrival_date.watch is not a function`

Comment: You might need to look at **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1269692/2065039)**