# Javascript load from php and onchange variable

Tags: javascript, php, function, onchange

i have a script that loads some div ids from php and every x seconds reloads the new values.. I want to implement an onchange value inside the script in order to trigger loading a new variable if (in this example artist changes) but i cant figure out how.. 
the script is:

```
setInterval(function(){
    cache: false,
    $("#artist").load("test.php #artist");
    $("#song").load("test.php #song");
}, 2000);
```

I need to tell if artist changes then load a new variable from php, using this wrapper code i found here  [How can I make a program wait for a variable change in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635924/how-can-i-make-a-program-wait-for-a-variable-change-in-javascript)?

```
function Wrapper(callback) {
    var value;
    this.set = function(v) {
        value = v;
        callback(this);
    }
    this.get = function() {
        return value;
    }  
}
```

If i use the same example with input box:`<input type="text" onchange="wrapper.set(this.value)"/>`
it works.. But i cant figure out how to make it work using the #artist pulled from the php in the first part..

I tried doing this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
        cache: false,
        $("#artist").load("test.php #artist").onchange(wrapper.set(this.value));
        $("#song").load("test.php #song");
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

and a lot of other combinations but neither works.. Can you help me please!

PS: Keep in mind that im a startet in javascript..

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You are missing something here for a start `$("")`. I'd advise you to use firebug in firefox to debug the code

Comment: @InGodITrust sorry mate small typo havent noticed my bad.. i removed it.

Comment: you still have one more of those ^^

Comment: Try this i haven't tested this script so it may work     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('input[name=status]').change(function(){
      $({
      url: "http://example.com/test.php",
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      data: {
          value: "$('input[name=status]').val()"
      }
  }).done(function(a) {
      $("#artist").html(a)
  })
  });//end change
  });//end ready </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
    cache: false,
    $.get('test.php',function(data){
     var artist = $('<div>' + data + '</div>').find('div#artist').html();
     if(artist != $('#artist').html()){
          $('#artist').html(artist );
          wrapper.set(artist)
    } //in here I assumed #artist is a div or span,... if its a textbox change it to $('#artist').val()
    });
    $("#song").load("test.php #song");
}, 2000);
```

Comment: there was no html code in your question.if #artist is a textbox just tell me to edit the answer.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, thank you very much, but it gives me every 2sec all the html data.. My syntax regarding artist in php file is "echo "<div id=\"artist\"> $artist </div>";" How can i make it to work only for artist and only if the name changes ?

Comment: It works perfect now.. Thank you.. If i wanted to take the $artist variable from the test.php with this script how could this be done, rather than getting the div? Im just curious :)

Comment: please vote up too ;) well in your php file you can just echo the artist name without anything else no html tags no script.

Comment: if you had just read the name not the div then variable data would contain the artist name no extra effort would be needed to extract it.

Comment: Now i get it thanks for pointing this. I wish i could vote u up but i need more than 15per else i would definitely vote u up :) Thanks once more for helpin