# setTimeout with dynamic duration in recursive loop

Tags: javascript

I want to write a code that capture an object asynchronously, so it needs to wait for a while. When it gets the object, it stops waiting and move on. So far this what I have:

```
function captureObject(obj,id) {
    var i =1;
    while (obj.value === '' && i<10) {
        i++;
        (function(i,obj) {
            setTimeout(
                function() { 
                    if(obj.value === '') {
                        // do stuff here
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                },
                1000 * i
            );
        })(i,obj);
    }
}
```

Basically I want to achieve: if `obj.value` is an empty string, keep waiting until it reaches 10 seconds and return `true`. If within 10 seconds it gets something, return `false`. But the code doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: JavaScript is meant to be synchronous, so the concept of "wait until something happens, then continue" doesn't really exist.  At best, you can implement "wait until something happens, then *do this specific thing*", but there's no real pause/resume in JavaScript.

Comment: once you started with asyncronous calls you cannot just return. Use callbacks or promises

Comment: _"[How can I make a program wait for a variable change in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635924/)"_  may be a better dupe, on second thought.

Comment: OK thanks you guys, let me just close this questions. Thanks for the help