# javascript wait for function to finish execution before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous

I am trying to set a global variable within a function, but the code continues before the variable has been updated. 
e.g.

```js
        var username = 'Example';
 const fetch = require('node-fetch');
 var num = 1234;
 var uuidP;
 const request = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${username}`);
  const json = await response.json();
  uuidP = json.id;
 }
 request();

 console.log(num); //returns 1234
 console.log(uuidP); //returns udefined
```

Comment: This is simply false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a program wait for a variable change in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635924/how-can-i-make-a-program-wait-for-a-variable-change-in-javascript)

Comment: Where is the function call ?

Comment: You didn't call the function update()

Comment: ASDFGerte well this is the cause of an error for me.

Comment: Code Maniac fixed

Comment: @Edaz this does gives the desired result, after you added the function call. where's the problem now ?

Comment: @CodeManiac I updated it to show my real code not an example if that helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @ASDFGerte this question is not a duplicate because I am not using ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is heavily optimised. You need to declare the update() function is asynchronous, and then use a Promise to await the response of the update. Have a look at this [example](https://javascript.info/async-await).