# jQuery how to Bind on a data bind?

Tags: jquery, data-binding

```
<div id="conversations-uCount">0</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#conversations-uCount').data('UnreadIDs', '1');
});
</script>
```

How can I set a bind so that any time the UnreadIDs changes I can run a function?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery 1.4.4+ there's an event [triggered for this, `changeData`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/data.js#L185).  If that's the only data you're dealing with on the object, your handler is as simple as:

```
$('#conversations-uCount').bind("changeData", function() {
  //data changed, do something, for example:
  alert("Data changed!, new value for UnreadIDs: " + $.data(this, 'UnreadIDs'));
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/3QxRb/).

Comment: Awesome - I was unaware of this addition in 1.4.4!  Good news.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could do that with a simple plugin:

```
$.fn.dataTrigger = function(name, value, callback) {
    $(this).data(name, value);
    callback(name, value);
    return this;
};
```

Then:

```
$('#conversations-uCount').dataTrigger('UnreadIDs', '1', myFunc);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/q6apA/1/

Comment: Not sure what's going on here?

Comment: @AnApprentice - as in, apply some method at the time of writing the data (and using `.dataTrigger` instead of `.data`). I hope I understood your Q :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a function called watch `object.watch` but its not standard, I think what your looking for can be found here [Object.watch() for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers)