# How to detect creation of new global variables?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, global-variables

I want watch for the creation of new global variables in Javascript so that, anytime a global variable is created, an event is fired.

I've heard of the `watch()` function but that is only for watching for specific variable names. I want a catchall.

Comment: I'm writing a framework which takes any variables inserted into the global namespace and places them in a data structure for tracking.

Comment: Perhaps this post will inspire some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers

Comment: `window` is special. The best you can do is polling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to make this work "on demand" as soon as a var is created, but I can suggest a polling approach. In a browser window, all global become a member of the global "window" object. (Because technically, "window" is the "global object").  So you could do something like the following:

1) enumerate all the properties on a window

```
window.proplist = window.proplist || {};
for (propname in window) {

    if (propname !== "proplist") {
      window.proplist[propname] = true;
    }
}
```

2) Set a timer to periodically "poll" window for new properties

```
setInterval(onTimer, 1000);
```

3) Wake up on the timer callback and look for new props

```
function onTimer() {
        if (!window.proplist) {
            return;
        }

        for (propname in window) {

              if (!(window.proplist[propname])) {
                 window.proplist[propname] = true;
                 onGlobalVarCreated(propname);
              }
        }
}
```

Comment: `foreach` isn't a valid keyword! And place the `if (window.proplist)` checks outside the `for` loop.

Comment: NO FOREACH IN JAVASCRIPT! Won't give you -1, fix that. `for(var propname in window)` would work.

Comment: Oops...good catch guys.  Fixed above. The poster only hasn't earned enough stackoverflow points for me to actually test my answer (or optimize it!). :)

Comment: @Cipi https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/For_each...in your wrong ;)

Comment: @Raynos: Chrome 9.0 doesn't have "for each" nor "foreach"... where can I use that?

Comment: This also doesn't handle deletion and recreation.

Comment: @Cipi but JavaScript has `for each` :)

Comment: While this solution works, it doesn't tell you where was the global variable created...

Answer (score 6):

If you already know which names pollute your global namespace (see [Intercepting global variable definition in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985224/intercepting-global-variable-definition-in-javascript)), you can use this trick to figure out *when* does it actually happen:

```
window.__defineSetter__('someGlobalVar', function() {
    debugger;
});
```

Be sure to have your developer tools open when you run this.
Obviously works only if your browser supports `__defineSetter__` but that's true for modern browsers. Also, don't forget to remove your debug code after you've finished.

Found [here](http://ext.ensible.com/blog/2013/01/squash-variable-leaks-with-siesta/).

Comment: This should be the approved solution

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, `.watch()` is only SpiderMonkey (Firefox).

I played around with a polling function, I finally came up with this:

```
var mywatch = (function() {
    var last = {
        count: 0,
        elems: {}
    };    

    return function _REP(cb) {
        var curr = {
                count: 0,
                elems: {}
            },
            diff = {};

        for(var prop in window) {
            if( window.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
                curr.elems[prop] = window[prop]; curr.count++;
            }
        }

        if( curr.count > last.count ) {
            for(var comp in curr.elems) {
                if( !(comp in last.elems) ) {
                    diff[comp] = curr.elems[comp];
                }
            }
            last.count = curr.count;
            last.elems = curr.elems;

            if(typeof cb === 'function')
                cb.apply(null, [diff]);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            _REP(cb);
        }, 400);
    };
}());
```

And then use it like:

```
mywatch(function(diff) {
    console.log('NEW GLOBAL(s): ', diff);
});
```

Be aware that this only handles **new** globals. But you can easily extend this for the case `last.count > curr.count`. That would indicate that global variables were deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have an event fired when some script does `var v = 10`, but as selbie said, you can poll the window object... I meant to suggest the same, but he beat me to it. Here's my other example... you count how many window objects are there, and execute GlobalVarCreated() function:

```
var number_of_globals = 0; //last known globals count

var interval = window.setInterval(function(){

   var new_globals_count = 0; //we count again
   for(var i in window) new_globals_count++; //actual counting
   if(number_of_globals == 0) number_of_globals = new_globals_count; //first time we initialize old value
   else{
     var number_of_new_globals = new_globals_count - number_of_globals; //new - old
     if(number_of_new_globals > 0){ //if the number is higher then 0 then we have some vars
         number_of_globals = new_globals_count; 

         for(var i = 0; i<number_of_new_globals; i++) GlobalVarCreated(); //if we have 2 new vars we call handler 2 times...
     }

   }

},300); //each 300ms check is run


//Other functions
function GlobalVarCreated(){}
function StopInterval(){window.clearInterval(interval);}
```

You can load up that code in Chrome or FF console only change: `function GlobalVarCreated(){console.log("NEW VAR CREATED");}` and test it:

`var a = 10`

`b = 10`

String `NEW VAR CREATED` is displayed 2 times.