# Intercepting global variable definition in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, global

I'm trying to tidy up some javascript code and one of the steps is removing all useless (or plain wrong) global variables that have slipped in from errors like:

```
for (prop in obj) { ...
```

instead of

```
for (var prop in obj) { ...
```

JSLint helps a bit in finding out this nastiness, but it is not 100% foolproof when the nastiness happens at runtime.
**I already tried to add some monitoring code that routinely checks the global scope logging to the console if some new variable is detected,** and that helped some more, but when it tells me that a new global variable named "i" has been detected ... well, it's a mess finding out where that happened in thousands of lines of code.

So here we come: is there a better way/tool/script/whatever to find the little pests?
My dream is something like a Firebug plugin that stops the execution whenever a new global variable is created...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now intercept variable definition as explained on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088203/how-to-detect-creation-of-new-global-variables)

```
window.__defineSetter__('sneakyVariable', function() {
    debugger
})
```

and you'll be able to find where it was defined

Answer (score 3):

You may find this [bookmarklet](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-global-variable-leaks/) useful.

Also, checkout this answer: [How to detect creation of new global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088203/how-to-detect-creation-of-new-global-variables)

Comment: Thanks, but what you suggest is basically what I already do with my monitoring code (i.e.: polling the global scope). What I am really looking for is something more like a conditional breakpoint on the definition of a global variable. I'm well aware that the answer to that may be "not possible" but, well hope die last :)

Comment: Yeah, window object is a special object. Polling is I think the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could set a timeout to create a list of all global variables and then compare that against the last time the timeout fired. I found this on Stack Overflow, and maybe you could use this code in conjunction with a setTimeout() to get what you want.

> Blockquote
>   Yes and no. "No" in almost every situation. "Yes," but only in a limited manner, if you want to check the global scope. Take the following example:
>       var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

```
for ( var i in window ) {
    console.log(i, typeof window[i], window[i]);
}
```

Stack Overflow link: [Getting All Variables In Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope)

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I said I already do which is polling the global scope for new variables.

Answer (score 0):

well, I wrote this long time ago, so code sucks, but it does the job: https://gist.github.com/1132193
paste in the firebug console or include as a script.

Answer (score 0):

You say, you are trying to tidy up some code.
In that case - use IDE, like [NetBeans PHP](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) (free) or [JetBrains WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) (30$). They both color global variables, and do lots of other useful stuff ;)
If your polling script will still detect creation of global variables - trace down offending functions, and make them suffer ;) Eventually, the code will become clean.