# Javascript loop-problem with setTimeout/setInterval

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout, setinterval

```
var flag = 0/1 (default=1)
```

- I want this flag to checked every 30sec over and over until the flag becomes 0 (by an external event that I cant control).
- When the flag is 0 the 30sec-check should end until the flag is 1 again
- As long as the flag is 0 some text should blink on the screen, if the flag goes back to 1 the blinking should stop and the 30sec check should continue.

I tried to do this with setTimeout/setInterval but Im having problem combining them with loops.

Here is some code doing the blinking from another site:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function init() {
    window.setInterval(blink,1000);
  }

  function blink() {
    var elm = document.getElementById('blinkDiv');
    if (elm.style.color == "#ff0000")
      elm.style.color = "#ffffff";
    else
      elm.style.color = "#ff0000";
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
<div id="blinkDiv" style="color: #ff0000;">some text</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers I will try them. This is my own try that seems to work OK:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function controller(){
            if(!f)
                setTimeout("blink();", 1000);
            else if(f)
                setTimeout("controller();", 30000);
        }

        function blink(){
            var elm = document.getElementById('alert');
            if (elm.style.color == "#ff0000")
              elm.style.color = "#ffffff";
            else
              elm.style.color = "#ff0000";

            controller();
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout` - you are implicitly calling `eval` with that. Instead, you cann pass it a reference to the function you want to call, like `setTimeout(blink)` and `setTimeout(controller)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
function init() {
  //start timeout to see if flag has changed in 30 seconds
  window.setTimeout(checkState,30000);
}

var blinkIntervalID;

function checkState() {
  if(flag==0) {
    // if flag is 0 then start the blinking interval
    blinkIntervalID = window.setInterval(blink,1000);
  }
  else {
    //else clear the blinking interval and set the text to normal state
    window.clearInterval(blinkIntervalID);
    stopBlink()
  }
  // Start timeout again to check in 30 seconds if flag has changed
  window.setTimeout(checkState,30000);
}

function blink() {
  var elm = document.getElementById('blinkDiv');
  if (elm.style.color == "#ff0000") {       
    elm.style.color = "#ffffff";
  }
  else {
    elm.style.color = "#ff0000";
  } 
}

function stopBlink(){
    var elm = document.getElementById('blinkDiv');
    elm.style.color = "#ffffff";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkIntervalId = null;
    var blinkIntervalId = null;
    var flag = 1;
    var elm = document.getElementById('blinkDiv');
    function init() {
        checkIntervalId = window.setInterval(check,30000);
    }
    function check() {
        clearInterval(blinkIntervalId);
        if (flag==0) {
            blinkIntervalId = window.setInterval(blink,1000);
        }
    }
    function blink() {
        if (elm.style.color == "#ff0000")
            elm.style.color = "#ffffff";
        else
            elm.style.color = "#ff0000";
    }
</script>
```

If you change the `flag` value by external functions, you need to leave the interval for checking if its changed or not. You can change this interval to 5 sec for ex. so it will faster detect change.

Other way is to change `flag` not directly but by setter function for ex. `setFlag(1)` and inside this function you can set and disable interval.

Answer (score 1):

You could use (the non-standard) [watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) (supported in Firefox) or this [cross-browser version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers/1270182#1270182) (supported in all recent browsers) to monitor changes to your flag, instead:

```
var flag = {value: 1};
flag.watch("value", function(id, oldval, newval) {
    if (newval === 0)
        blink();
    else 
        stopBlink();
});
```

The function passed to `watch` will be executed every time `flag.value` changes, so there's no need to monitor it with timeouts. (Of course, if the 30 second wait is a hard requirement, then you're back to `setTimeout` or you'd need to track the elapsed time since the flag last changed.)