# Start/stop function with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've got a simple `setInterval` function for radio buttons to loop on load.
I would like to add a button, which could start or stop the loop. I've added click function for the function, but don't know how to stop it afterwards.

Here is what i've got so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5HDPY/)

Also, if i click the button more times in a row, loop goes berserker - any help appricieted :)

p.s. I've also checked:
[start & stop / pause setInterval with javascript, jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539079/start-stop-pause-setinterval-with-javascript-jquery?rq=1) and
[Javascript loop-problem with setTimeout/setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142383/javascript-loop-problem-with-settimeout-setinterval?rq=1)

but i was wondering in the dark on how to use those answers as i'm javascript noob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a reference to your `setInterval` so you can use `clearInterval(yourreference)`.
To start / stop, you can add an extra boolean variable to toggle start and stop.

```
var t;
var running = false;

$("#start-stop").click(function(){
    clearInterval(t);
    running = !running;
    if (!running) 
        return;
    t = setInterval(function(){
        $('.wrap input')
        .eq( ( $('input:checked').index() + 1 ) % 3 )
        .prop('checked',true);
    },1000);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5HDPY/4/)

Comment: This won't stop it... It's stop the duplicate intervals, but not stop the animation...

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
jQuery(function () {
    var timer;
    $("#start-stop").click(function () {
        if (timer) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = undefined;
        } else {
            timer = setInterval(function () {
                $('.wrap input')
                    .eq(($('input:checked').index() + 1) % 3)
                    .prop('checked', true);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RZe9g/)

Comment: Thank you, your works great also - wish i could give 2 accepted answers. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

le solution without clearInterval

```
jQuery(function () {
   var toggle = null;
    $("#start-stop").click(function () {
        if(toggle == null) {
            toggle = false;
            setInterval(function () {
                if(toggle)
                    $('.wrap input').eq(($('input:checked').index() + 1) % 3).prop('checked', true);
              }, 1000);
        }   
        toggle = !toggle;
    }); 
});
```

[Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/RZe9g/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any advantage with this method over another ones?

Comment: I don't know if it is faster if you check every second... or generate your timer every click.

Comment: So your code should be more efficient/optimized? Sorry for asking, i don't know much about javascript/jquery.

Comment: I don't know it... its just an other way to do it. You get a little timeshift between those solutions thats all i know :)