# Javascript Encapsulation and Compound Assignment Operator

Tags: javascript, oop

My aim to to create an object in Javascript where I can easily just go `block.red = 128;` or `block.red += 5`. Which could easily be done using `this.red` inside the object, but I want my object also be able to do which is stumping me is to ensure that the red value falls within the accepted range (i.e. not above 255 and not below 0).

I've had a bit of a look around, and one thing I thought might work was encapsulation. The problem being then is that I can't use the compound assignment operator. Obviously this isn't the end of the world, but I would like to know if there are any solutions that I haven't thought up.

```
function colours(r, g, b) {
    _r = r;
    _g = g;
    _b = b;

    this.red = red;

    function red(value) {
        if (value == undefined) {
            return _r;
        } else {
            if (value < 0) {
                _r = 0;
            } else if (value > 255) {
                _r = 255;
            } else {
                _r = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

// tests
colours(240, 120, 60);
alert(red());
red(120);
alert(red());
red(360);
alert(red());

// works up to here
red() -= 30;
alert(red());
```

So do you have any ideas of how I can keep the compound assignment operator while still ensuring the red value stays within range?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282507/how-to-run-a-function-in-javascript-every-time-a-variable-changes) is what you are looking for.

Comment: The "Object Watch" looks like it would work, seems like an interesting debugging tool that could be useful.

Comment: Notice that you forgot [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) before the variables, and are not invoking your constructor with `new`. It should be `var c = new colours(240, 120, 60); alert(c.red()); …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getters and setters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) as one way to achieve this.

---

```js
// our constructor function
function Color(r, g, b) {
    return {
        get red() {
            return r;
        },

        set red(value) {
            // let's make sure we get a number here
            if ( typeof value === 'number' && !isNaN(value) ) {
                // check the range
                if (value < 0) {
                    r = 0;
                } else if (value > 255) {
                    r = 255;
                } else {
                    r = value;
                }
            } else {
                // this gets set if they don't pass a number
                r = 255;
            }
        }
        // other color methods here
    };
}

// --------------------

var red = new Color(255, 0, 0);

alert(red.red); // 255

red.red -= 55;  // assignment within range, success

alert(red.red); // 200

red.red -= 999; // assignment out of range, failure

alert(red.red); // 0

red.red += 999; // assignment out of range, failure

alert(red.red); // 255
```

---

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/thetenfold/LzLG3/)

Comment: Just omit the underscores and those three variable :-)

Comment: Sorry, I kind of copied what he originally had and modified it. You're right, I can use those parameters like that.