# dispatchEvent(new Proxy(event, {}) does not work

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dom-events, dispatchevent, es6-proxy

I'm working on an app which uses events. The modules of the app execute in separate containers and I thought about using Proxy to tame the events that are fired. However, I cannot seem to be able to make `dispatchEvent` accept an event that has been proxied.

The following fails:

```js
let event = new CustomEvent('my event');
let eventProxy = new Proxy(event, {});
let eventTarget = document.createElement('div');

try {
    eventTarget.dispatchEvent(eventProxy); // VM134:4 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

Anyone has any ideas how `dispatchEvent` can be made to accept proxies?

Comment: What do you mean by "*tame the events that are fired*"?

Comment: restrict/filter property values depending of the container in which the event is being caught.

Comment: `new Proxy(event, {})` does not create a fully transparent replacement object. You need a lot more to handle that unfortunately.

Comment: @loganfsmyth what more?

Comment: @hldev In the generic case, you need a everything that crosses a proxy boundary to be wrapped, so you should _never_ return any object from a proxy handler unless it is also wrapped in a Proxy. This is generally referred to as a "membrane": https://tvcutsem.github.io/js-membranes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177855/how-to-create-a-deep-proxy-aka-proxy-membrane

Comment: @loganfsmyth this membrane won't make `dispatchEvent()` accept proxied object

Comment: @hldev If you have a membrane then _every_ access should go through the membrane, so it would be the membrane's job to unwrap the proxy and pass the underlying event object as the argument for `dispatchEvent` since `dispatchEvent` is also something from outside the membrane. It's very complicated, which is why I'd generally say using a Proxy as a generic "programmable object" is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an old question, but It may help someone, because I didn't find similar Q&As about this.

As pointed in the comments:

> Proxy will not create a fully transparent replacement object.

You can also log out `eventProxy` and see that most of the properties are unaccusable.

My suggestion is wrapping your `Event` with an object that has a function that returns the event. (for multiple events, you can even use that object for a gateway to all events).

Then, dispatch the event that returns by calling that function.

Now, when you proxy the new object, you can override the `get` in the handler to log the call.

```js
let event = new CustomEvent('my event');
let eventWrapper = { getEvent: ()=> event };
let handler = {
get: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    console.log('Logged!');
    return Reflect.get(...arguments)
  }
}
let eventProxy = new Proxy(eventWrapper, handler);
let eventTarget = document.createElement('div');

try {
    eventTarget.dispatchEvent(eventProxy.getEvent());
    console.log("Done!")
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```