# Is there a way to monitor changes to an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

Instead triggering an event based on user action can you just listen for changes to an object and react then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, depending on the domain you're working with, you can use [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) - it has a "model" object that you can extend and connect up to callbacks that get triggered by events automatically when the model is changed - that is, you set a field on the model, and it will automatically fire an event that you can listen to. You have to define your models to extend its Model, and call a setter function instead of setting properties directly, but it's very useful, I recommend it.

Just for clarity's sake, the event is fired *from the model on change*, so it's fired even if you set the value of the attribute programmatically or in the console.

Comment: Thanks Matt, backbone looks like a great option.

Answer (score 5):

I've written something like this.

https://github.com/jmoyers/mettle

```
person.on('name.change', function(val){
    // 'a new name was committed: Yolanda'
    console.log('a new name was committed: ', val)
});

person.name = 'Yolanda';
```

https://github.com/jmoyers/mettle/blob/master/src/model.coffee

It might be a little much to dig through all the source. Here's an explanation:

The key for my project is two concepts. One is to keep the track a set of attributes and create getters and settes for each using **defineGetter** and **defineSetter**. The second is to 'subclass' EventEmitter and broadcast events based on these property changes in your setter.

Track shows how I set up getter/setter for a set of keys.

```
  Model.prototype.track = function(keys) {
    _.each(keys, __bind(function(key) {
      this.tracked.push(key);
      this.__defineGetter__(key, __bind(function() {
        return this.get(key);
      }, this));
      return this.__defineSetter__(key, __bind(function(val) {
        return this.set(key, val);
      }, this));
    }, this));
    return this;
  };
```

Here's an example of how to broadcast based on a 'magic' setter:

```
  Model.prototype.set = function(key, val) {
    this.attribs[key] = val;
    this.emit('change', this.attribs);
    type = key + '.change';
    this.emit(type, val);
  };
```

This is a simplified example, since I introduced 'attribute middleware' into the mix, but this shows how you could emit a change event based on a property change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getters and setters ro react on properties change. John Resig have written great [article](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) about them.

Comment: You can also use a [`Proxy` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to detect changes to an object.