# Observing Display Changes in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add an observer to a DOM element that is triggered on changes to the visibility (i.e. calls to `show()` and `hide()`)? Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if you can try this out for style.display? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers/1270182#1270182

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to observe *any* call to `.show()` or `.hide()` and have access to jQuery 1.5+ you could use [`jQuery.sub()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/) to create a copy of the jQuery object to override the default `.show()` or `.hide()` actions.

```
var myjQuery = jQuery.sub();
myjQuery.fn.hide = function() {
    alert('hide');

    return jQuery.fn.hide.apply(this, arguments);
};
myjQuery.fn.show = function() {
    alert('show');
    return jQuery.fn.show.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

And then using the `.sub()` copy

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".click").click(function() {
            if ($("#hide").is(":visible")) {
                $("#hide").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#hide").show();
            }
        });
    });
})(myjQuery);
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/qdP5P/)**

Comment: +1 Excellent answer.  I hadn't seen this yet in jQuery 1.5+.  I'll definitely be using it at some point in the not too distant future.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible out of the box that I know of, but if changes happens through jquery you can easily add the tracking yourself by using a custom event like this:

```
// save the jquery.show() method
$.prototype.base_show = $.prototype.show;
// provide your own that trigger the event then call the original one
$.prototype.show = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    // call your custom event, add any parameters you need there
    $(window).trigger('on_jquery_show'/*, params you need*/);
    // now call the "real" show method
    $.prototype.base_show(speed, easing, callback);
    // return this so you can chain it
    return this;
};
// add some callback to that custom event
$(window).bind('on_jquery_show', function() { console.log('show !'); });
// it works !
$('#some_div').show().show();
```

Same thing for hide().

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

For example:

```
 $('#divID').show('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
 });
```

See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: So how would using: `$('#divID').show('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
 });` have that called back if you for example make all `div`s visible with: `$('div').show();`? It's a callback on the completion of that particular show/hide, not an event listener which monitors the changes to the visibility of that element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're showing and hiding using the jQuery mechanisms, you might try using the [Live Query](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin.

> Live Query also has the ability to
>   fire a function (callback) when it
>   matches a new element and another
>   function (callback) for when an
>   element is no longer matched.