# Listen to state and function invocations

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to listen to any function invocation or state change

I have a object that wrap another

```
function wrapper(origiObj){
   this.origObj = origObj;
}
var obj = wrapper(document);//this is an example
var obj = wrapper(db);//this is an example
```

now everytime someone tries to invoke obj.innerHTML or obj.query(..)

I would like to listen to that..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible:
functions are easy, and properties has to be watched

```
function FlyingObject(obj){
    this.obj = obj;
    for(var p in obj){
        if(typeof obj[p] == 'function'){
            console.log(p);
            this[p] = function(){
                console.log("orig func");
            };
        }else{
            this.watch(p,function(){
                console.log("orig property");
            });
        }
    }
}
var obj = {
    f:function(a,b){ return a+b},
    m:1
};
var fo = new FlyingObject(obj);


fo.m = 5;

fo.f(1,4);
```

If your browser/node.js doesn't support Object.watch, check this out:
[Object.watch() for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, define a `getter`/`setter` for properties and a shadow function for the function like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fHRyU/1/.

```
function wrapper(origObj){
   var type = origObj.innerHTML ? 'doc' : 'db';
   if(type === "doc") {

      var orig = origObj.innerHTML;

      origObj.__defineGetter__('innerHTML',
                               function() {
       // someone got innerHTML
          alert('getting innerHTML');
          return orig;
      });

      origObj.__defineSetter__('innerHTML',
                               function(a) {
       // someone set innerHTML
          alert('setting innerHTML');
          orig = a;
      });

   } else if(type === "db") {

       var orig = origObj.query;

       origObj.query = function() {
           //someone called query;
           alert('calling query');
           orig.apply(this, arguments);
       };

   }

   return origObj;
}

var obj = wrapper(document.body);
obj.innerHTML = 'p';
alert(obj.innerHTML);

var db = function() {}
db.query = function() {alert('foo');}

obj = wrapper(db);
obj.query();
```

Comment: A couple things to point out about this: no IE support, and you have to manually wrap every property you may want to catch.

Comment: But node.js is not IE if I'm not wrong. But you're correct about your second point.

Comment: :)  Didn't notice the `node.js` tag

Comment: The wrapper could easily be rewritten to work for any obligatory property and trigger events.

Answer (score 0):

edit: "Deleting" answer since it's tagged node.js, leaving it in case it happens to be useful to anyone else:

<strike>The general answer is no, it isn't.  At least not in every browser, so any solution anyone gives isn't going to work in many cases.</strike>

There are a few things that can work, but again there is horrible support for them:

- dom modified events (FF only, I believe)

  - DOMAttrModified
  - DOMNodeInserted
  - DOMNodeRemoved
  - etc
- object.watch (FF only)