# jQuery tags or badges documentation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tags

I'm trying to use the [jQuery tags input](http://xoxco.com/clickable/jquery-tags-input#instructions) plugin, but there is not much documentation. I need to define event handlers for when a tag is added or removed. I guess I could make an [object watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers) on the output string to determine this, but that is quite awkward.

Comment: Found http://projects.alicialiu.net/jquery-tagify-demo/ but not much help...

Comment: ...and this http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tagger

Comment: ...and this http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking into the [source code](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input/blob/master/jquery.tagsinput.js) for the tags input plugin, there currently seems to be support for callbacks for `addTag()` and `removeTag()`.

there appears to be 3 callback handlers you can register when you create the tag list.
They are:

1. onAddTag
2. onRemoveTag
3. onChange

when you create your tag list, try setting functions to these on the options object you pass it:

```
$(selector).tagsInput({
   onAddTag: function(value){
   // Do Stuff
   },
   onRemoveTag: function(value){
   // Do Stuff
   },
   onChange: function(tagList, value){
   // Do Stuff
   }
});
```

Note: I haven't tested this, but the source code indicates this should work.