# jQuery on variable change, update textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jQuery, is is possible to check if `var x = []` changes, and then add the contents of the array to a textbox.

So if x contains `["1","2","3"]`. My textbox `textbox1` value will be `"1","2","3"`

Comment: This previous post may help... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers).

Comment: If you'd use a function to change the value of x, you don't need a watcher (if it's possible at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this to avoid using a watcher:

```
var Data = (function () {
    var _x = [],
        $textbox = $("#myTextbox");
    return {
        getX: function () {
            return x;
        },
        setX: function (x) {
            _x = x;
            // Setting 'x' triggers an update
            $textbox.val(x.join(","));
        }
    }
}();
```

And then set the value of `x` using `Data.setX(x)` and get it using `Data.getX()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = myArray.join(',');
$('#textbox1').val(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about watching a variable for a change, unless you create an object that has an "onChange" event, but to show the values in the textbox use this...

```
$("#textboxID").val(x.join(","));
```

The easiest thing would be to have an update function with the above code and just call that everywhere you change the value of x.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($.inArray(x, [1, 2, 3]) != -1) {
    $('#textbox1').val(x);
}
```

Comment: I think that it is not checking for one particular content which is important but to check when the content of x changes...