# always convert into object

Tags: javascript, json

Can I do something in Javascript that will automaticaly transform this:

```
var x = 0;
```

into the following (but only in memory-- I don't want to change the "view source"):

```
var x = {Value: 0};
```

For exemple:

```
var x = { Value: 0 };

function a(x)    //This function doesn't work if the parameter is not an object, and it would be better if I didn't have to write { Value: 0 }
{
    x.Value++;
}
a(x);
alert(x.Value);
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you would use that?

Comment: "it would be better if i don't have to write" an object where an object is required?!? just use `typeof x` inside your function

Comment: no, i mean that the variable is still an object but the declaration of the object is automatic

Comment: What you're looking for is called "pass by reference" and doesn't exist in javascript - for a reason, because in most cases it's a bad idea.

Comment: @thg435 uh.. objects are passed by reference in javascript

Comment: @deathApril: no they are not. Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy carefully.

Comment: @thg435 if you pass an object to a function and the function changes this parameter, the original object is changed - i don't care what do you want to call it..

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean when you say you don't want to change the "view source"? Do you mean you don't want it to show up in the source at all? [Why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133817)? What's so important about not assigning an object to `x`?

Answer (score 1):

The question lacks context and details, but maybe do it like this:

```
function transform(x) {
     return { Value : x };
}
```

and then

```
x = transform(x);
```

Comment: and can I associate each declaration of a variable with this function ?

Comment: No, you cannot override variable declaration behavior in Javascript and you need to decorate variable declarations manually or perform the transformation in some other endpoint (e.g. have your own console.log())

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) and [Object.watch() for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers), e.g.:

```
var a = function (x) {
    x.value++;
};
var myVariables = {};
myVariables.watch("x", function (prop, oldval, newval) {
                     if (typeof newval !== 'object') {
                         return {"value": newval};
                     };
                 });
myVariables.x = 0;
a(myVariables.x);
alert(myVariables.x.value);
```

Comment: The **watch** function is non-standard- best to avoid.