# Debugging: Is it possible to see value of JS variable in real time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, firefox, firebug

Is there any tool (preferably extension/add-on to any browser) that allows you to see all the value changes of the desired JS variable in real time?

Previously I did something like this (in pure JS):

```
var someVariable;
var previousValueOfSomeVariable;
var f = function() {
  if (previousValueOfSomeVariable != someVariable) {
    console.log(Date.now(), someVariable);
    previousValueOfSomeVariable = someVariable;
  }
}
var TO = setInterval(f, 100);
```

It did the trick, but was, of course, inefficient (in reality the function was bigger, while it required object-copy function if variable was an object and further checks)...

**UPDATE**

I'm aware of console tools, but I'd like to see the history of changes, like:

`someVariable`

0ms: `undefined`;

10ms: `5`;

40ms: `'someothervalue'`;

150ms: `null`

etc.

(Milliseconds are given for example purposes, not necessarily required). Maybe it can be done within the DevTools console, but I don't know how.

Comment: You can always open up the console and go to the JavaScript file you're interested in and step through the code.

Comment: Might be able to of more help with a longer description of what you need, but I would just open of the browser console (right click -> inspect element) and set breakpoints where necessary.

Comment: @rsahai91, thanks for your response. I've updated the question. Hope it's easier to understand what I want now :-)

Answer (score 4):

Chrome dev tools has functionality for this.

insert the line

```
debugger;
```

right after the variable you're interested in.  When your page executes and dev tools is open it will pause there and you can inspect the console.log with the value it had at that moment.

For example - say you have an onClick handler and want to see what information is passed in the event:

html:

```
<input onClicked={myFunc} />
```

JS

```
function myFunc(event){
  console.log(event)
}
```

This will log the event to the console, but if you try to drill down chrome evaluates the obj when you click on it and since its long gone, its mostly null:

[image: Screenshot of Normal console.log]

However if you use debugger, chrome pauses execution when it hits that and you can dig into the real event:

JS:

```
function myFunc(event){
  console.log(event);
  debugger;
}
```

Lets you drill down into the object as it was at the time you hit the debugger line

[image]

More info in the chrome dev tools site:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints

Comment: And if one wants to try it out... https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_debugger

Answer (score 1):

The different DevTools (tested in Chrome DevTools, Firefox DevTools and Firebug) don't offer a way to see the value changes in real time. You always have to refresh their display manually.

Firefox offers an [`Object.prototype.watch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) function (for other browsers [there is a shim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270182/432681)), which does what you want.

## Example:

```
test = 0;
setInterval(() => test++, 1000);

window.watch("test", (id, oldValue, newValue) => {
  console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), newValue);
  return newValue;
});
```

This will output something like this:

> 09:51:03 1
>   09:51:04 2
>   09:51:05 3
>   09:51:06 4
>   09:51:07 5

*Note: This function only allows to watch single properties of an object, so, in order to watch all object properties you need to loop over them and call `watch()` for each one.*

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes object.watch . It isn't used very often though! Here is a more detailed post of what I think you're looking for [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome Users

Step 1: Go to DevTools settings (the cog wheel).

Step 2: Check Preferences > Sources > Display variable values inline while debugging.

Follow this link Note : the answer is bit old so follow above updated steps in current chrome version
[Preview JavaScript values inline while debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/preview-javascript-values-inline-while-debugging/)