# PyQT4: "TypeError: Attempting to configurable attribute of unconfigurable property."

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have some problems observing event-propertys of html elements in a QWebpage with pyqt. The webpage I want to load and execute with pyqt:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script>
/*
 * object.watch polyfill
 *
 * 2012-04-03
 *
 * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com
 * Public Domain.
 * NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.
 */

    // object.watch
    if (!Object.prototype.watch) {
        console.log("Watch defined...")
        Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "watch", {
            enumerable : false,
            configurable : true,
            writable : true,
            value : function(prop, handler) {
                var oldval = this[prop], newval = oldval, getter = function() {
                    return newval;
                }, setter = function(val) {
                    console.log("Set: " + prop);
                    oldval = newval;
                    return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
                };
                console.log("Before if statement...")
                if (true) { //here in original code is: "delete this[prop]", in every browser it is true but in a QWebpage not... why?
                    console.log("After if statement: " + prop
                        + " is observed...")
                    Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                        enumerable : true,
                        configurable : true,
                        get : getter,
                        set : function(val) {
                            console.log("Set: " + prop)
                            oldval = newval;
                            var newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val)
                                    || val;
                            return newval;
                        }
                    });
                } else { 
                    console.log("Error: can't be observed")
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // object.unwatch
    if (!Object.prototype.unwatch) {
        Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "unwatch", {
            enumerable : false,
            configurable : true,
            writable : false,
            value : function(prop) {
                var val = this[prop];
                delete this[prop]; // remove accessors
                this[prop] = val;
            }
        });
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="target" href="#">LINK WITH HANDLER</div>

<script>
    link = document.getElementById("target");
    //
    //link.onclick = myClick2
    link.watch("onclick", function(prop, oldVal, newVal) {
        console.log("watch > onclick has changed!!");
        return newVal;
    });
    link.onclick = myClick;

    function myClick(e) {
        console.log("Dear sir, here is a click");
    }
</script>
```

When I'm putting that in a html-page and execute it on a browser(Chrome, Firefox, Epiphany, ...) I get the desired behaviour and could read the console log 
message.

But when I'm trying to load the page with QWebpage in python with pyqt4(I also tried pyqt5) then the page doesn't behave in the same way.
After some tests, I noticed the problem is in the if-statement. In every browser it is true, in contrast using QWebpage. When I'm deleting it, then I get the error message from the headline.

Can someone please tell me why this is so and what is the different in a webpage rendered with QWebpage and a normal browser using the same JavaScript engine?
I hope I give enough information. Thank you for your help!

Here is the code to fetch the html page:

```
import sys
import logging
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
from time import time, sleep
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.Qt import QApplication


class Browser(QWebPage):

def __init__(self, app, proxy = "", port = 0):
    QWebPage.__init__(self)
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
    self.app = app

def get(self, requested_url, timeout=20):
    logging.debug("Browser started on {}...".format(requested_url))
    self._loading_complete = False
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(requested_url))
    t = 0
    while(not self._loading_complete and t < timeout ): # Waiting for finish processing
        self._wait(0.1) 
        t += 0.1

    if not self._loading_complete:
        logging.debug("Timeout Occurs")

    self._analyzing_finished = True
    return self.mainFrame().toHtml()

def _loadFinished(self, result):
        if result:
            self._loading_complete = True

def _wait(self, waittime=1):
    """Wait for delay time
    """
    deadline = time() + waittime
    while time() < deadline:
        sleep(0)
        self.app.processEvents()

def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, message, lineNumber, sourceID):
    logging.debug("Console: " + message + " at: " + str(lineNumber))       
if __name__ == '__main__':

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                datefmt='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S',
                #filename='Crawler.log',
                #filemode='w'
                )

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
browser = Browser(app)
browser.get("http://localhost/") #Console output is important
```

Comment: Which `if` statement are you referrring to? (And note that WebKit uses its own [Javascript engine](https://www.webkit.org/projects/javascript/)).

Comment: The if in the JavaScript-Code: [...]if( delete this[prop])[...]

Comment: The `delete this[prop]` returns `false`, but I can't see how you're getting that error. Please post a complete, self-contained example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Here are now the html page, that should be loaded with qwebpage and and the python code to do that. I have edited the original question text.

Comment: The [source of the webkit js engine](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/webkit/source/26a95e634c52382518001482c89948ef3eea181e:src/3rdparty/webkit/JavaScriptCore/runtime/JSObject.cpp#L559-573) (around line 570), shows that the error is thrown when trying to re-define an existing property descriptor that is not configurable. This means that, in webkit, `onclick` is *not* a configurable property, whereas it seems that it *is* in other browsers. I don't know why this is. It could be a bug, or it could be that webkit is complying with some standard that the other browsers aren't...

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Have you an other idea how I can observe the change of .onclick and other event-propertys with pyqt?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have discovered why the return value `delete` is different. The javascript spec allows browsers to implement `delete` in whatever way they like, and as a result of this, it seems that you cannot rely on the correctness of its return value.

To give an example, here's what happens in Firefox (using Scatchpad):

```js
// page = about:blank

document.body.onclick;
/*
null
*/
document.body.onclick = function(){alert('boo!')};
/*
function (){alert('boo!')}
*/
delete document.body.onclick;
/*
true
*/
document.body.onclick
/*
function (){alert('boo!')}
*/
```

Liar! It is clearly **not** possible to delete the `onclick` property, but Firefox returns `true` anyway. This leads me to the tentative conclusion that the webkit javascript engine may actually be doing the right thing here, and it is the other browsers that have the problems.

For more information about the behviour of `delete`, see the excellent article [Understanding delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#delete_and_host_objects), and in particular, the section [`delete` and host objects](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#delete_and_host_objects).

Comment: Thank you for the two artickels... can you give me a hint how I can observe with pyqt when an event-attribute is attached to a html-element?

Comment: @Pumba88. Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1029241/984421)? The accepted answer is the same as the one in your question, but there are other solutions there that you could try out. Alternatively, Qt-5.4 will be available very soon, which has the chromium-based [QWebEngine](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtWebEngine) classes. The current [PyQt5 snapshot](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) already has support for QWebEngine.

Comment: Yes I know that question and have also tried the proposed solutions...but nothing works. Ok maybe I will wait or try the snapshot. Thank you very much!!