# Fire event on boolean change (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I am creating an app where users earn trophies based on input. I want to alert the user when they earn a trophy. I'm uncertain how to write:

```
var trophy = false
if (userInput) {
    trophy = true
}

// alert user when boolean changes from false to true after userInput
```

All the solutions I come up with alert the user when the boolean is true (which is every instance after the change), but I just want to alert once on change. The boolean will only ever flip once; once it's true, it never goes back to false.

Thanks!

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/object-watch-for-all-browsers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object.watch() for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/object-watch-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the value just before you change it:

```
var trophy = false
if (userInput) {
    if (!trophy) {
        // alert user here
    }
    trophy = true
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!